# Are temporary objects in C++ const indeed?

Tags: c++, constants, temporary

I always believed that temporary objects in C++ are automatically considered as const by the compiler. But recently I experienced that the following example of code:

`function_returning_object().some_non_const_method();`

is valid for C++ compiler. And it makes me wonder - are temporary objects in C++ const indeed? If yes, then why the code above is considered correct by the compiler?

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary objects"?

Comment: Who or what gave you the idea that they were const in the first place?

Comment: @Fred: Probably because they can be bound to `const T&` but not `T&`.

Comment: So if they are not const - why can't they be bound to T&?

Comment: @mrn: Thought so. Temporaries only being able to bind to `const T&` is a decision, not a requirement. All references could easily refer to a temporary object, but it turns out there's pit-falls when you let things use a `T&` referring to a temporary, so it's not allowed.

Comment: @GMan: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670137/)

Answer (score 6):

No, they're not.  Not unless you declare the return type as const.

Comment: I think the OP was hoping there's something in the standard that explains this.

Comment: The way the standard would "specify" something like this is by not ever requiring that temporaries be const.  It doesn't.

Comment: @chrisayrock -- Why would the standard need to say that?  Objects are not const by default.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

```
int f();
const int g();

class C { };
C x();
const C y();
```

In the case of both `f()` and `g()`, the returned value is not const because there are no const-qualified rvalues of non-class type.  The `const` in the return type of `g()` is completely useless (in fact, it's worse than useless, since it can in rare circumstances cause issues with template instantiation).

In the case of `x()`, the returned value is not const (because it isn't const-qualified).  In the case of `y()`, the returned value is const (because the return type is const-qualified).  The `const` qualifier here (or lack thereof) is meaningful because the return type is a class type.

Comment: related: [non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169932/)

Answer (score 5):

Answering the question first, they are not actually const. You may not bind one to a non-const reference. This was probably done to prevent errors in certain situations where they would be passed as a parameter to a function that modifies them, only for the changes to be made to a temporary object and not the intended target.

Allowing non-const operations on a temporary is especially useful when you wish to call "swap" on it with a local variable.

```
std::vector<T> local;
method_that_returns_a_vector().swap( local );
```

Before the days of move semantics, this was considered the most efficient way to return a large data set and acquire it without copying all the data.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary objects *can* be const, but they don't have to be.

```
((string const)"hello").append(" world"); // error!
```

It allows for various things. Consider

```
struct bitref {
  int index;
  bitref &operator=(bool value); // non-const!
};

struct bitset {
  int flags;
  // returns a bitref temporary that's associated with the bit
  // at index 'index'. 
  bitref operator[](int index); 
  // ...
};
```

You could do

```
bitset b;
b[1] = true; // change second bit to 1
```

This is what's done by the `std::bitset<>` template.

Comment: Haven't seen a -1 on your answer in a while. :) +1 Wonder why. EDIT: Looks like you've got a hunch. :o

Comment: @GMan yeah I have. I better not show it to others though. I'll do fairplay :)

Comment: Haha, ok. We'll see if you get your comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Temporary objects aren't const, but they can only bind to const lvalue references. It's easy to demonstrate that allowing temporaries to bind to non-const lvalue references would be bade in virtually all scenarios. You also can't take the address of a temporary, even though you can bind a reference to it, and a number of other very silly things happen with regards to temporaries in C++03. Just be glad that C++0x will be here soon... hopefully.

Comment: `struct C { C* operator&() { return this; } };`  ... `C* x = &C();`  OMG!  I took the address of a temporary!  :-D  (I know; I cheated...)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the return type of the function.

```
//Temporary objects: nameless objects that are only usable in current statement
Object function();           //Return a temporary object by value (using copy constructor)
const Object function();     //Return a const temp object by value

//references, return a reference to an object existing somewhere else in memory
Object & function();         //Return an object reference, non-const behaves as any other non-const
const Object & functon();    //Return const obj reference, behaves as any other const
```