# Temporary Objects and pass by (const/non-const) `value`

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

Life time of temporary objects last until the full length of the expression in which it was created when used `without references`.

Consider the following:

```
 class My
 {
   int i;
   public:
     void increment()
     {
       i++;
     }
 };

 My withOutConst()
 {
   return My();
 }

 const My withConst()
 {
   return My();
 }

 int main()
 {
   My ob;
   withOutConst().increment();  // Case 1
   withConst().increment();     // Case 2

   return 0;
 }
```

As I understand the compiler creates a `temporary` object( of type `const My`) to hold the return value in the above cases.
And, I am trying to modify the temporary object.

`(1)` Compiles fine and

`(2)` Results in a compile time error with the error:

`error: passing 'const My' as 'this' argument of void My::increment() discards qualifiers`

That means basically `this` is of type `My` and not `const My` as it is called for a `non-const` function.

My question:

I am trying to modify a temporary object of type `const My` by calling a `non-const` member function.

Then why don't I get the same error in case(1) because I am operating over an object of the type     `const My` in both the cases.

I understand that this is related to the `return type` of the functions but am unable to fully comprehend because at the end it boils down to the function(`void My::increment()`) which is trying to modify temporaries of type `const My` in both the cases.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did something in C++, but what purpose does the `My ob;` serve?

Comment: In case 1, your temporary is not `const`. So you can call non-const methods on it. This isn't the case in Case 2.

Comment: An important thing to remember here is that you created two functions which essentially create objects `My x` and `const My y`, respectively. So, really, your `My ob` serves no actual purpose. It is likely the compiler simply has optimized this to what I noted above.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701558/are-temporary-objects-in-c-const-indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary has a type, that type can be const, and it can be non-const. You can call a non-const member function only on a non-const object. `withOutConst()` yield a temporary of type `My`, `withConst()` yields a temporary of type `const My`.

Maybe you have the misconception that a temporary is always `const`? If that is the case, then it is wrong.

Comment: But I was going through `thinking in C++` it says that compiler automatically makes temporaries `const`. This led me to this question.

Comment: @UchiaItachi: The book can say that, but temporaries are not `const` automagically, as you have already noticed.

Comment: Yes, I agree because its working in the above case. But, consider
I have one more function `void change(My &ref)` and I am calling it as `change(withOutConst())` I get an error here too, but it vanishes if the function is `void change(const My &ref)` doesn't that mean the temporary is of `const` type?

Comment: @UchiaItachi: I understand. The question is fine, the answer is just what it is :)

Comment: @UchiaItachi: No, it does not mean that the temporary is `const`. the calls to both `withOutConst()` and `withConst()` are *rvalue* expressions, `const My&` and `My&` are both *lvalue*-references. You cannot bind a (modifiable) *lvalue* reference to an *rvalue*. There is a special rule in the language that allows binding a `const` *lvalue* reference to the *rvalue* (whether `const` or not) by extending the lifetime of the *rvalue* to match the lifetime of the bound reference. But that is a specific rule for binding references.

Answer (score 0):

> Then why don't I get the same error in case(1) because I am operating over an object of the type const My in both the cases.

That simply isn't true.

```
 My withOutConst()
 {
   return My();
 }

 const My withConst()
 {
   return My();
 }
```

`withOutConst` returns an object of type `My`, while `withConst()` returns an object of type `const My`.  Even though in both cases you are using them as temporaries, their underlying type `My` and `const My` are exactly as coded in the function signatures.

Answer (score 0):

1. Returns a temporary non-const object, calls the function on it, then it goes out of scope.
2. Returns a temporary const object, which does not allow non-const function to be called.

A temporary object does not have to be const.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand the compiler creates a temporary object( of type `const My`) to hold the return value in the above cases.

No. The return value of `withOutConst()` is not `const`, since you didn't declare it `const`. The observed behaviour follows from that.

You may be confusing being `const` with being an *rvalue*. In many situations, an *rvalue* can't be modified; but you *can* call a nonconstant member function on one.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a simplified version of something you're trying to do in a more complex code base, where you still want to use some some sort of counter on a const object, then you need to mark your "i" variable as "mutable". Like so:

```
class My
{
   mutable int i;
public:
   void increment()
   {
      i++;
   }
};
```