# What is the difference between temporary variable and constant in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, pass-by-reference, pass-by-const-reference

Allow me to post my code first:

```
void Fun(short &s){}
void FunCon(const short &s){}

int main()
{
  int iTest = 20;//note: iTest is int but parameter of Fun is "short &"
  Fun(iTest);//error, I know there is a temp variable(typecast)
  FunCon(iTest);//ok
  return 0;
}
```

I know `Fun(iTest);`will generate a new **temp variable**(typecast), but I wonder if the temp variable is a **constant**?

If **No**: Why can't I pass the temp variable to `short &`

If **Yes**: I have another code like this:

```
class MyObject{
  public :
  void F(){}
};

MyObject MOCreator(){
  return MyObject();
}

int main()
{
   MOCreator().F();//OK
   return 0;
}
```

If temp variable that returned by `MOCreator()` **is constant**, why the **temp variable** can call **non-const member function**?

My questions are：

**1)** What is the difference between **temporary variable** and **constant** in C++?

**2)** There is a sentence in *Thinking in C++*(page 507). Is the sentence right? and why?:

> Temporary objects are automatically **const**

I was asked for a simple question by someone, and I encounter more questions on my way to solving the question. I do know they may be a very common questions,and I am searching for a long time on net. I also got many different answers. But I'm more confused about it now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if the temp variable is a constant?

No, it's just a temporary variable which will be destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it was created.

> Why can't I pass the temp variable to short &

A temporary can't be bound for a non-const reference. But it could be bound for const reference, and the lifetime of the temporary will be extended to match the lifetime of the reference. That's why `FunCon(iTest);` is fine.

> why the temp variable can call non-const member function?

It's fine. The only special thing is the temporary variable will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.

> Is the sentence right? and why?
>   Temporary objects are automatically const

No. Unless you explicitly declare it to be const.

Comment: "Temporary objects are automatically const" Is the sentence right?

Comment: @Joe I don't know the context of it, I'll say it's wrong only for this single sentence.

Comment: @Joe See [Are temporary objects in C++ const indeed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4701558/3309790).

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous temporaries are rvalues, which can only be bound to an rvalue reference or a `const` lvalue reference.  So your temporary `short` can be bound to a `short&&` or a `const short&`.

They are not `const`; the main purpose of rvalue references is to alter them by moving expensive-to-copy resources out of them and into a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following:

```
void f(short& s) {
   s = 42;
}
```

Now consider this simple use case:

```
short s = 0;
f(s);
std::cout << s << "\n";
```

This will print 42 - calling `f` had the side effect of modifying `s`.

But now consider the following, if it were legal:

```
int i = 0;
f(i);
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

This would print 0 because what you would be modifying in f is the temporary, with the original `i` untouched.

To prevent this behavior, you can only pass a temporary to a const reference or an rvalue reference.