# How many times will copy constructor be called if a function pass by value and return by value

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I understand that `f(ClassA str)` pass by value and return by value, so

`f(str)` call copy constructor 2 times;

`f(f(str))` call copy constructor 4 times;

`str1 = f(f(str))` call copy constructor 5 times.

But the result is 2,3,3.

Moreover, if i change the definition of `f` into `ClassA f(ClassA &str),` there is a error `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`. How could this error come?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassA
{
    int a, b;
public:
    ClassA()
    {
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
    }
    ClassA(const ClassA &obj)
    {
        a = obj.a; b = obj.b;
        cout << "copy constructor called" << endl;
    }
};

ClassA f(ClassA str)
{
    return str;
}

int main(){
       ClassA str;
       ClassA str1;
       str1 = f(f(str));

}
```

Comment: *How many times will copy constructor be called...* -- It depends on your compiler, compiler version, optimization settings, etc.  There is no concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPD:
ClassA explicitly declare only copy constructor.
So, ClassA **has** defaulted **copy assignment operator**

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly.
>   If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared
>   copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted

And **hasn't** defaulted **move constructor**

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly
>   declared as defaulted if and only if
>   (8.1) — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   (8.2) — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   (8.3) — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>   (8.4) — X does not have a user-declared destructor.

Instead, **move constructor** ClassA use **copy constructor**

> Note: When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that otherwise
>   would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor. — end note ]

**Copy elision** happen in f(f(str))

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of
>   a non-volatile automatic object (...) with the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function
>   return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the automatic object directly
>   into the function call’s return object

Summaries:
***f(str)*** - by default : copy constructor + move constructor; in this case : copy constructor + copy constructor

***f(f(str))*** - by default : copy constructor + copy elision + move constructor + move constructor; in this case : copy constructor + copy elision + copy constructor + copy constructor

***str1 = f(f(str))*** - in this case : copy constructor + copy elision + copy constructor + copy constructor + copy assignment operator (not copy constructor [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor))

It's possible to have another result, for example, if use flag "-fno-elide-constructors" in gcc. It disables copy elision
[Disabling g++'s return-value optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758152/disabling-gs-return-value-optimisation)

**f(str)** return rvalue object. In **ClassA f(ClassA &str)** you take lvalue references.
Interesting that ClassA f(**const** ClassA& str) doesn't give error [Const reference and lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845167/const-reference-and-lvalue)

Comment: Is this correct, where you can pinpoint a certain number (3 in your case)?  The number of times a copy constructor is invoked depends on the compiler and various optimization settings.